# Problem with Spark regarding Pandas API, dataframe and UDF

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

**I have already solved it.
To start with, I need to install the same version of pyspark as Spark:
`pip install pyspark==3.4.0`
Then, I needed to put two lines of code in the cell:**

```
import os
import sys
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
```

**Thus, it works properly!**

Dears,

I work locally with Spark on Jupyter Notebook. I learn new transformations to proceed with ETL/ELT transformations using PySpark.

I am able to read .csv files and parquet files using PySpark Dataframe.
However, If I try to create my own DataFrame based on data, I will encounter this difficulty:

```
columns = ["Seqno","Name"]
data = [("1", "john jones"),
    ("2", "tracey smith"),
    ("3", "amy sanders")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=columns)

df.show(truncate=False)
```

I run this cell and it appears:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonFunction. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonFunction([class [B, class java.util.HashMap, class java.util.ArrayList, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.util.ArrayList, class org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:180)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:197)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:237)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

If I run a cell with this code:

```
technologies   = ({
    'Courses':["Spark","PySpark","Hadoop","Python","Pandas","Hadoop","Spark","Python","NA"],
    'Fee' :[22000,25000,23000,24000,26000,25000,25000,22000,1500],
    'Duration':['30days','50days','55days','40days','60days','35days','30days','50days','40days'],
    'Discount':[1000,2300,1000,1200,2500,None,1400,1600,0]
          })
df = ps.DataFrame(technologies)
print(df)
```

It also appears the same error...

I have the same error when I intend to create a UDF function in Jupyter Notebook.

My Spark version is v3.4.0, Java version 20.0.1 and I use hadoop.dll and winutils.exe files for  hadoop 3.0.0

I have no idea what I should do because it works properly when I transform data with PySpark, but if I want to use these ones, this problem appears.
I browsed the internet and I try a lot of approaches, but none of them works.
Therefore, I am fed up with it and I decided to ask a question regarding this problem.

I would appreciate it if you could share any ideas on how to solve this problem.
I would like to add that I am a beginner in it.